# Stuck email open with notification of 500 unrecognized addresses

Tags: email, notifications

I received an email with 500 names, mostly political discussions, I decided I wanted to be off the list and when I made the request by replying the last person it cc'd all 500 names and it would not send, instead a notification dropped down over the email and said it doesn't recognize the recipients. The list is so long it drops below the email screen and it will not scroll down, no arrow key, nothing..just is stuck there
I pressed enter and it all just hides up into the upper portion of my screen, and I can minimize it..NOTHING closes it.. I did delete it from the outbox..but the damn letter is still there.. Help!! I have mac book pro OS 10 8 4

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot with Grab?

Comment: I would say just blur them.

Answer (score 1):

I was asked if I had tried the Escape button...(by my housemate) and so I did ..the long notification window with no bottom on it that was stuck over my email disappeared leaving me with my email that I intended to send to one person but ended up with 500 recipients that were not recognized by my computer..
I now could simply discard it.
I must say as I commented above..I feel a bit sheepish...